# Changing Default Rendering Of ToolStrip Item

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, forms

ToolStrip Control Rendering property can be changed by defining a Custom Class (to make it FLAT as shown in code below), I know this. But you have to do this in your visual studio project for each Form Control including ToolStrip. My question is:

> Is it possible to change Default Behavior of Any ToolBox Item in
> Visual Studio so not to write extra code?

```
public class MySR : ToolStripSystemRenderer
{
    public MySR() { }

    protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add new class and inherit from `ToolStrip`, override the `OnCreateControl` method to set the `Renderer` property to a new instance of your custom renderer. Rebuild, find your custom control on the `ToolBox` under _yourProjectName_ components. Use it instead of the default `ToolStrip`. To use it in other projects, create control library project instead.

Comment: brilliant idea, but it's a problem because the "TOOLSTRIP" class name is used throughout the project, we'll have to change it too, it's risky, thank you...

Comment: What's risky? Use a different name for your custom control. like `SoftWarToolStrip`. For the old strips in your forms, just change in the designers the type from `new ToolStrip` to `new SoftWarToolStrip`. Editing the designer file can be risky yes. So, always backup.

Comment: Do you mean application-wide renderer? If so, derive `MySR` from `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer`. In `main` and before `Application.Run(...)`, set [ToolStripManager.Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripmanager.renderer?view=netframework-4.8&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripManager.Renderer)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) to new instance of `MySR`.

Comment: ... and don't forget to do [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripmanager.renderer?view=netframework-4.8&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripManager.Renderer)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue#remarks).

Comment: "ToolStripManager.Renderer = new CustomProfessionalRenderer();" is not an application wide code, must be refer in each form.

Comment: I don't have time to argue. Please read my comments carefully and refer to the provided [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripmanager.renderer?view=netframework-4.8&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripManager.Renderer)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) and read it carefully.

Comment: anyway, thanks for taking time for this question...